# How to use the namespace "Windows.Globalization.Calendar" in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 8 do not support the namespace "Windows.Globalization.Calendar". Which namespace can be used in Windows Phone 8 instead of "Windows.Globalization.Calendar"?
Please help me I am new to Windows Phone 8 development.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: no, actually i searched but i could not find any thing relevant.

Comment: How does it not work for you? Asking about an alternative indicates that it doesn't work and that should really be part of the question

Comment: Accept my mistake, now its edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution by my self, which is "System.Globalization" Namespace which provides almost all the functionalities of  "Windows.Globalization".

Answer (score 2):

Try an opensource calender library:

[Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) or some more generic explanation here [which specifically mentions WP8](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/04/Noda-Time-1-1)

Answer (score -1):

FYI - While Windows Phone 8.0 does not support Windows.Globalization namespace classes, Windows Phone 8.1 (in universal apps) do.